# Write VueJS data binding expression in href of <a> tag

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, v-for

I'm using VueJS 2.0 with Laravel 5.3. I have Vue array data (e.g, `items`). Now I want to render those data in table using `v-for`. In table, there is a button to redirect page to item details page. For that, I'm writing my static URL till `/` in href of  tag. Then I'm appending {{item.id}}. But I'm getting this error.

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the
>   colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of ,
>   use `<div :id="val">`

So I can't get that how to write data binding expression of VueJS in `<a href="">`. If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Here is my code.

**my-items.blade.php**

```
<div id="app">
....
    <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>
            <a href="{{url('/item')}}/@{{item.id}}">view</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
....
</div>
```

**my-items.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            {id: 1},
            {id: 2},
            {id: 3}
        ]
    },
})
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I was doing in AngularJS with Laravel 5.2. And I want similar like this.

```
<a href="{{url('/item')}}/@{{item.id}}">view</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like following:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
    <td>
        <a :href="'{{url('/item')}}/' + item.id" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have done this as per your answer `<a :href="{{url('/item')}}/@{{item.id}}">view</a>`. But now getting this error `failed to compile template:`

Comment: Your answer has worked. But I want something like what I have commented in your answer. And in that way, it didn't worked.

Comment: It worked with this. `<a :href="'{{url('/item')}}/' + item.id">view</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to maintain fixed URL rather than relative URL, you may consider this one:

```
<div id="app">
    <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>
            <a :href="'{{ url('/item') }}' + '/' + @{{ item.id }}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done this as per your answer `<a :href="'{{url('/item')}}' + '/' + @{{item.id}}">view</a>`. But now getting this error `failed to compile template:`

Comment: And yes, I want something like that which you have answered. But not working.